# terraform code issues creating webapp runtime stack

Tags: terraform, azure-web-app-service

i am trying to create a windows webapp stack using terraform but it creates windows container service plan here is my code
can anyone please help

```
**code**

provider "azurerm" {
  version = "= 2.69.0"
  features {}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "functoss11"
  location = "East Asia"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "ASP-ush-9388"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  sku {
    tier = "basic"
    size = "B1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "example" {
  name                = "newddshaikh"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id

  site_config {
    dotnet_framework_version = "v5.0"
  }
  
}
```